# Book about people with psi abilities that end up travelling on a space craft

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

I read this book in the late 70’s/early 80’s. It is about people with psi abilities that end up travelling on a space craft. I can’t remember the author but he/she was very good. I borrowed it off my uncle and he couldn’t remember what it was called when I asked him about it in 2000 he passed away earlier this year and I am just trying to find what it was called and if I can get a copy from anyone. They guys will remember because the ladies were built well and they were called primes.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2058281.The_Warrior_Within?

Comment: In Anne McCaffrey's *The Rowan* and books set in the same universe, the best telepaths are known as primes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rowan

Comment: Are any of them vampires?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are probably many books that would match, but one possibility that occurs to me is [The Galaxy Primes](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22222) by (the legendary!) E. E. Doc Smith.

[image: The Galaxy Primes]

The protagonists are called Primes, they have telepathic powers and they are on a  spaceship.

> They were four of the greatest minds in the Universe: Two men and two women, all Psionic Primes, lost in an experimental spaceship billions of parsecs from home. And as they mentally charted the cosmos to find their way back to Earth, their own loves and hates were as startling as the worlds they encountered.

You mention the ladies are well built, and indeed the book starts:

> Her hair was a brilliant green. So was her spectacularly filled halter. So were her tight short-shorts, her lipstick, and the lacquer on her finger and toenails.

Comment: Sounds like a better match than my idea. I was thinking of Anne McCaffreys The Tower and The Hive series (Rowan Series), as they too are called primes and have telekinetic powers, but the spaceship doesn't fit so well.

Comment: I think the above is probably the answer, but all of E.E. Smith's works tend to have "well built" women and "chiseled" men as the protagonists. Antagonists tend to be either "slimy but good looking" types or fat. In many of the works important people are referred to as "prime operators" or something similar.

Comment: This is thank you so much John, and mwarren I have all the Anne mccaffrey books

Comment: @bob1 I would have expected Doc Smith to have kindly feelings toward fat people, considering his day job as a doughnut chemist.